# Button click listener in fragment. Android studio

Tags: android, button, fragment

I have a problem in trying to implement a button click listener in a fragment. I don't have a problem if there is just one button, but I have 3 buttons in the fragment UI.

This is what I get:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

The code, I made it as a public method

```
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);


  first=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_first);
  first.setOnClickListener(this);
  second=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_second);
  second.setOnClickListener(this);
  third=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_third);
  third.setOnClickListener(this);

  // Also I tried these ones but its not possible to :
  //first.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());
  //second.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());
  //third.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) getActivity());


    return view;
}

 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.button_first) {

     //some code here
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button_second) {
        //some code here
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button_third) {
       //some code here
        }
 }
```

I can implements one buttons listener as follow:

```
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment5, container, false);


  call= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
  call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v)
     {
         dialContactPhone("Some phone number");

     }

 });
      return view;
 }
```

But I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with the first code. Why there is a `null`?

Comment: Did you declarate your buttons ?

Comment: It would seem that at least one of `button_first`, `button_second`, or `button_third` is not in the `fragment_blank` layout.

Comment: yes, they are define in the xml layout with the corresponding id. I always copy the xml item id to findViewById. I dont know what is happening because its a simple code.

Comment: Are you certain those `Button`s are in exactly `fragment_blank`? They have to be in that one, specifically. If so, do you have multiple versions of `fragment_blank` – e.g., for the separate orientations, different Android versions, etc. – where all of those `Button`s might not be in each version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide your fragment class code in your first example but since you are using `.setOnClickListener(this)` and getting an error at that point in your code I am going to assume you did not implement `OnClickListener` in your class.  If you use "this" to set a listener and you did not implement `OnClickListener` in your class, there is nothing for setOnClickListener() to find.  This is what is causing your `NullPointerException`.

If you want to use "this" to set your listeners and use the method onClick(View view) to manage your clicks, your class must implement OnClickListener.

**Example:**

```
public class MyFragmentClass extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    // You can use "this" for .setOnClickListener() in this class
}
```

Comment: This would cause a compile-time error. The OP wouldn't've even been able to run the app, let alone get a runtime `Exception`.

Comment: @Mike M., please explain.  Are you referring to the fact that I forgot to put "extends Fragment"?  (I will edit that in a moment), or are you referring to some other issue.

Comment: No, I meant that this answer doesn't address the issue shown in the given `Exception` and its message.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

- fragmet_blank xml you can define **3 Button like** button_first , button_second, button_third using same id.

**java code**

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

Button f = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_first);
Button s = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_second);
Button t = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_third); 
f.setOnClickListener(this);
s.setOnClickListener(this);
t.setOnClickListener(this);
return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button_first:

   //some code here

    break;
}

  case R.id.button_second:

   //some code here

    break;
  }
 case R.id.button_third:

   //some code here

    break;
}
 }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me.
Setting click listeners for every button individually.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default, container, false);

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.sell)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your code
            }
        });
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buy)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your Code
            }

        });
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.bookbuddy)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your Code
            }
        });
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.listing)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your Code
            }
        });

return rootView;
```